# Git Clone not working form a Linux server using HTTPS and SSH

Tags: git, github

Unable to clone my own git repository from a Linux (Ubuntu 18) server (DigitalOcean). I have tried with both SSH and HTTPS but had no luck. Here are the steps I have followed:

1. Generate a key using ssh-keygen
2. Put that key on Github under SSH-keys

When I run `ssh -T git@github.com` it replies **Hi jfBiswajit! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.**

**Git clone using SSH:**

```
Cloning into '.'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Git clone using HTTPS:**

```
Cloning into '.'...
Username for 'https://github.com': jfbiswajit
Password for 'https://jfbiswajit@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
```

I have provided the correct user name and password. I could not understand what's wrong with it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that `ssh -T` works, but `git clone` with the `git@github.com` ssh URL does not, is very curious. This can happen on Windows because Windows has its own version of ssh, and Git has a different version, and sometimes they don't use the same files, but it shouldn't happen on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `ssh -vT git@github.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens and generate a token.

And enter the generated token instead of your password when you are cloning the repository.

Answer (score -1):

I would check if my `ssh-agent` is running

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

and has the key added to it.
Check for any keys with the agent by doing

```
ssh-add -l
```

Follow the official guide [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey#verify-the-public-key-is-attached-to-your-account) to add keys to the agent.